# Loads of opendirectoryd error messages in system log

Tags: macos, logs, open-directory

I'm seeing these errors in my MacOS (10.12.1) system log files in big amounts.

Any idea where this may coming from? Didn't have success finding anything usable on Google so far. They seem to persist even if all networking is switched off.

```
Standard    09:39:33.265256 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.265342 +0100   opendirectoryd  initiating reconnect of module connection
Standard    09:39:33.265609 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.265654 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.265724 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.266113 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.266205 +0100   opendirectoryd  disconnect module connection
Standard    09:39:33.266285 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.266356 +0100   opendirectoryd  initiating reconnect of module connection
Standard    09:39:33.266579 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.266620 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.266677 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.267075 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.267163 +0100   opendirectoryd  disconnect module connection
Standard    09:39:33.267528 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.267587 +0100   opendirectoryd  initiating reconnect of module connection
Standard    09:39:33.267826 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.267871 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.267941 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.268352 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.268467 +0100   opendirectoryd  disconnect module connection
Standard    09:39:33.268559 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.268637 +0100   opendirectoryd  initiating reconnect of module connection
Standard    09:39:33.268875 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.268922 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.268994 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.269330 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.269403 +0100   opendirectoryd  disconnect module connection
Standard    09:39:33.273528 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.273618 +0100   opendirectoryd  initiating reconnect of module connection
Standard    09:39:33.273968 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.274043 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.274194 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.274601 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.274679 +0100   opendirectoryd  disconnect module connection
Standard    09:39:33.275176 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.275252 +0100   opendirectoryd  initiating reconnect of module connection
Standard    09:39:33.275535 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.275575 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.275652 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.276009 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.276081 +0100   opendirectoryd  disconnect module connection
Standard    09:39:33.276184 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.276272 +0100   opendirectoryd  initiating reconnect of module connection
Standard    09:39:33.276542 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.276586 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.276655 +0100   opendirectoryd  queuing request to connection - '<private>'
Standard    09:39:33.276988 +0100   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Standard    09:39:33.277119 +0100   opendirectoryd  disconnect module connection
```

This is only a snippet - they keep posted to the log every few seconds.

Comment: Seeing the same thing, thousands every minute. Any info on how you work? Office? Adobe apps? Developer?

Comment: No Adobe Apps. Web Dev, MS Office, Dropbox,... the usual stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be due to Dropbox.  Try disabling it and see if the requests stop.

Comment: I did a little more research on this, and in particular, Dropbox doesn't like softlinks that don't point at anything

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I did use Etrecheck to clean a few broken links and some adware; it worked like a charm, now my console log is back to 'normal' and the CPU usage as well.

You could give a go, I recommend to do a backup before deleting any file but as I said, Etrecheck did a damn good job (http://etrecheck.com/).

Good luck.

Comment: That makes ZERO sense.  OpenDirectory (LDAP) has nothing to do with adware or broken links.